# Is there a name for "reducing words to a minimum" in presentations?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for the "technique" to reduce all sentences in a talk to the minimum?

nb: Perhaps we have to elaborate this question, but I do not know the right technical terms yet and am open for suggestions.

Comment: Two users downvoted the question without leaving any comment. Please leave a short note, how to improve the question.

Comment: Yes: revise, revise, revise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Concision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concision) might fit the bill.

If you don't feel like clicking the link:

> Concision (alternatively brevity, laconicism, terseness, or conciseness) is the art and practice of minimizing words used to convey an idea. It aims to make communication more effective by eliminating redundancy without omitting important information. Concision has been described as one of the elementary principles of writing.